# Can Drools Flow scale to executing hundreds of thousands of process instances per day?

Tags: java, workflow, drools, drools-flow

I'm currently evaluating Drools Flow as a workflow engine for executing up to hundreds of thousands of process instances per day. Has anyone published any scalability benchmarks for this technology? In the absence of published results does anyone have any relevant experience they can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drools Flow is about as fast as they come, it's very small and lightweight. If it struggles, then you'll need native code, we have an experimental native flow compiler - but I'd be very surprised if it is needed. If you have any problems contact us on the [Drools mailing list](http://labs.jboss.org/drools/lists.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just appear an official post about this [here](http://blog.athico.com/2009/06/drools-flow-performance.html)

Comment: +1 - Great, thanks (although the post is not that enlightening)